# jQuery ASP input Validation with Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Currently: successfully executing input validation. The input borders are highlighted red, which is exactly what I need.

The solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429129/textbox-validation-with-jquery), but I also need to add a tooltip to any of the fields that are left blank.

I'd also like to fill each tooltip with a message explaining the user error.

```
function validationHelper() {
   var isValid = true;
   $('#textBox1,#textBox2,#textBox3,#textBox4').each(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            isValid = false;
            $(this).css({
                "border": "1px solid red",
                "background": "#FFCECE"
                //do I add tooltip property here?
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({
                "border": "",
                "background": ""
            });
        }
    });
    if (isValid == false) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a multitude of solutions for adding a tooltip via javascript. You'll likely want to store the message in data attributes on the fields and then generate/show a tooltip upon invalid entries. It certainly will not go within `css()` as in your example.

Comment: okay, good to know. ill update this upon some extra work. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend **Bootstrap** javascript library for the tooltips.

You can do something like this in your HTML

```
<input id="textBox1" type="text" title="Error text here" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
<input id="textBox2" type="text" title="Error text here" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
<input id="textBox3" type="text" title="Error text here" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
<input id="textBox4" type="text" title="Error text here" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
```

Then your javascript to activate the tooltip would be (**triggering manual**)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#textBox1,#textBox2,#textBox3,#textBox4').tooltip({'trigger':'manual'});
});
```

And your function would be

```
function validationHelper() {
   var isValid = true;
   $('#textBox1,#textBox2,#textBox3,#textBox4').each(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            isValid = false;
            $(this).css({
                "border": "1px solid red",
                "background": "#FFCECE"
            });
            $(this).tooltip('show');
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({
                "border": "",
                "background": ""
            });
            $(this).tooltip('hide');
        }
    });
    if (isValid == false) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Read the **documentation** to change the position of the tooltip (top/bottom...) or any other parameter you want to add/remove.

Documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

**Note**: I didn't have time to try it in a fiddle, please try and let me know if that fixes your issue or at least helps in any way :)

Comment: just curious, does it matter if each Textbox has to be an html input, or is ASP textbox okay?

Comment: You didn't mention ASP so I assumed you referred to html inputs

Comment: no problem, thanks for the clarification. Anyway, I hope my answer helps you at least for guidance of where to look